# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object when call gameObject from 2d array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had a 2d array
After instantiate, i set `GameObject` to my array and try to call it from array by index and use `getComponent`, it works fine.
But in next time of for-loop, calling exist array's GameObject by index return null when i try getComponent 
Someone has idea or resolution ?!
Thanks for your help !

[image]

[image]

Comment: It means (Block) Component doesn't exist in my GameObject ?! I tried to get other component such as Image, it still works fine. I haven't removed any Component before. Do you know why (Block) Component disappear ?! Thank you !

Comment: in the first one it is called on [i,j] in the second call, it is on [1,0].. is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc1dU.png)
This problem appears because I created 2 array to same new GameObject[,] so when i set GameObject to fruits2,it also set same element of blocks array and made (Block) component disappear